# Qt5 application cant file Qt5Networkd.dll and Qt5SerialPortd.dll

Tags: qt, serial-port, qt5

After finished my application in QT5 i've just run the build on release mode.
I have no errors in the terminal but i got 3 System Errors like that:

[Qt5SerialPortd.dll    Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVpR.jpg)

[Qt5Networkd.dll       Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2nhI.jpg)

And a 3rd one, but i solved that by downloading it from dllfiles.com, the error was the same with the two above, but the dll name was Qt5Cored.dll and that's the only one that i've found.

Now, i dont know what to do so i can run my GUI application.
Help me with some information about this issue!
Thank you!

Comment: ***And a 3rd one, but i solved that by downloading it from dllfiles.com*** Never download these dlls. Get them from your installed Qt that you are using to build your application.

Comment: ***but the dll name was Qt5Cored.dll*** That is the debug version.

Comment: If your release mode program is dependent on either of these files you have a configuration problem in your project. These dlls are debug mode dlls. Even if you put the debug dlls in the correct folder your program may run but the result will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, i deleted that dll from my PC, now i just searched those dll's in my qt6 files but i didnt find any of these dll with d at the end of its name.

Comment: I run the program with the release mode but i still get the errors that it cant find the dlls. How can i identify the config problems? I've searched the internet and didint find anything helpful. I checked the .pro file in my project and i cant just import these dlls i already have in my project.

Comment: How can i install the qt app with the debug version dll's ? Cause i've installed multiple times this app and i got sick of this phase :))

Comment: @drescherjm do i need a license to have access to these dlls? Cant wait for your answer!

Comment: If you are developing with Qt you must have accepted at least the open source license and your Qt SDK / kit you installed should contain the release and the debug dlls. I build Qt from the source code using either a script a wrote or more recently use vcpkg to build it for me.

Comment: Ok, i just started using it 3 days ago and i still have the free license with the 10 days free trial mode. I just created an account and i checked the files in my Qt installation folder and i didnt find any of the debug dlls, i just have the simple dlls Qt6Core/Qt5Core.dll not Qt5/Qt6Cored.dll
You think i should buy a lincese now ? The one with 400$ a month? @drescherjm

Comment: I believe you selected the wrong download option. And the wrong version of Qt. You can download a version of Qt5 still and you can use the opensource license without paying any fee. If you are building a commercial application to sell then you probably want a developer license. I work in medical imaging research so I use the open source license which I have done so since 2008.

Comment: @drescherjm Can you give me a link of what should i download? I downloaded qt-unified-windows-x86-4.2.0-online.exe

Comment: Start here and select Qt 5.15.2 for your compiler: [https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4)

Comment: Thank you, let me try this and i ll keep you up to date!

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/pKi9r286z-ZM) _italic_ **bold** 
Thats all the versions i can choose from. Should i just uncheck all the other options that are already checked? 
@drescherjm

Comment: I guess pick 5.15.1 and make sure you select your compiler. msvc and mingw have different binaries.

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/cTBXWY_LhwFg)
Thats what i chose, i use windows and the app will only run on windows for the moment

Comment: MSVC in for windows and MinGW is for linux, m i right?

Comment: No both are options on windows.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. I solved the problem by using the config with MinGW, and it worked on Qt Creator 5.15.2, i've fount it by checking the option LTS. Thank you so much! Hope you have a good day!!